# How to simply read in input from stdin delimited by space or spaces

Tags: python, stdin, raw-input

Hello I'm a trying to learn python,
In C++ to read in string from stdin I simply do

```
string str;
while (cin>>str)
    do_something(str)
```

but in python, I have to use

```
line = raw_input()
```

then

```
x = line.split()
```

then I have to loop through the list x to access each str to `do_something(str)`

this seems like a lot of code just to get each string delimited by space or spaces
so my question is, is there a easier way?

Comment: The C++ code seems cryptic and filled with implicit assumptions.  What's your **real** question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python doesn't special-case such a specific form of input for you, but it's trivial to make a little generator for it of course:

```
def fromcin(prompt=None):
  while True:
    try: line = raw_input(prompt)
    except EOFError: break
    for w in line.split(): yield w
```

and then, in your application code, you loop with a `for` statement (usually the best way to loop at application-code level):

```
for w in fromcin():
  dosomething(w)
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really an "easier" way, since Python doesn't have built-in formatted string functions like C++ does with `iostream`.

That said, you could shorten your code by combining the operations:

```
for str in raw_input().split():
   do_something(str)
```

Comment: your code would propagate an `EOFError` exception when standard input is done (you really need a `try`/`except` to handle that -- e.g., see my answer).  Calling `split` directly on `raw_input()`'s return value, rather than assigning the latter to an intermediate variable, is indeed feasible, but I think that keeping them separated results in more readable code (since you should write a generator for it anyway, saving one line is no big deal IMHO).

Answer (score 0):

```
map(do_something, line.split())
```

Comment: Explanation missing, please add some words to your code.